# Android App LVL protection cracked

Tags: android, cracking, android-lvl

my Android App obfuscated with Proguard and protected by Googles LVL has been cracked probably by a tool like  [Lucky Patcher](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xpqu1g_how-to-remove-licence-verification-of-android-apps-rooted-mobile_tech)  removing the License check :-(

Do you know of any better ways of implementing the Google License Check, possibly modifying the licence library as described  [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html)  or using some other technique preferably without communicating with a server.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, follow the guidelines in the article and change the default LVL implementation. More specifically, get the cracked version and try to find exactly what they changed, then focus on that part.

Comment: yeah, did that, hopefully it will last

Comment: If you get the APK cracked version. Then how do you see the source code. It will be in APK file and compiled version of obscated code

Comment: There are multiple tools that do this, and if you have the ProGuard seeds you can deobfuscate. Usually changes are made by using smali/baksmali, so you can use those tools to compare byte code from the cracked app and your original one.